# I need to Click "Open" on a Edge Browser Popup using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, webautomation

I need to click "Open" on the browser popup using selenium.
Please help me to click "Open" using selenium and C#.
[image: Popup to open a file]

I have tried using switching to active window to alert, but It says its not a alert.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a browser specific dialog. Selenium cannot interact with them... only the page itself and JS dialogs. Depending on the browser, there are options you can set to automatically download files, etc. that you may want to investigate.